# Dropping outliers using standard deviation and mean formula

Tags: python, pandas, mean, outliers, standard-deviation

---

Hello everyone,

I am trying to remove the outliers from my dataset. I defined the outlier boundaries using the mean-3*std and mean+3*std. Now I want to delete the values smaller than mean-3*std and delete the values bigger than mean+3*std. Could you help me writing a formula for this? I am a beginner in python. I already looked at similar questions, but this did not helped so far.

Untill now I had the following:

```
import pandas as pd

print(df_OmanAirTO.mean()-3*df_OmanAirTO.std(), df_OmanAirTO.mean()+3*df_OmanAirTO.std())
```

resulting in:

```
FuelFlow                2490.145718
ThrustDerateSmoothed       8.522145
CoreSpeed                 93.945180
EGTHotDayMargin            9.950557
EGT                      684.168701
TotalAirTemperature       11.980698
ThrustDerate              -3.780215

dtype: float64 

FuelFlow                4761.600157
ThrustDerateSmoothed      29.439075
CoreSpeed                101.360974
EGTHotDayMargin           90.414781
EGT                      915.952163
TotalAirTemperature       43.266653
ThrustDerate              44.672861

dtype: float64
```

Now I want to delete the values smaller than mean-3*std and delete the values bigger than mean+3*std. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to apply the outlier conditionals on each column (i.e. in column `FuelFlow`, remove cells smaller than `2490.145718` and larger than `4761.600157`, and in column `ThrustDerateSmoothed`, remove cells smaller than `8.522145` and larger than `29.439075`, etc...)

I will try this:

```
filt_outliers_df_oman = df.apply(lambda x: x[(x < df_OmanAir[x.name].mean()-3*df_OmanAir[x.name].std()) & 
                                             (x > df_OmanAIr[x.name].mean()+3*df_OmanAir[x.name].std())], axis=0)
```